# Accessing Google Translation Service (C# WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, google-translate, machine-translation

I've seen many websites AND programs that access the google translation service.

I'm trying to create a little app where there are basically 2 TextBox controls and a Button, where you can select a language to translate from and to.

But how do I access the API? I've not found anything so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send WebRequest to

> **http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}**

,
where 
0 = your text to translate, and 
1 = language pair separated by "|" delimiter